# onclick not getting executed

Tags: jquery

Part of the code is not being executed. The animatition to open the box is working fine. but the animation for closing is not working. What is wrong?

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $("#basic-modal-content").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.hide();
            dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                dialog.data.slideDown('slow');   
            });
        });
    }}); 

    $("#basic-modal-content").modal({onClose: function (dialog) {
        dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

}});

Comment: `modal` is not a jQuery thing. What other libraries are you using?

Comment: Also, showing us your HTML might help resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, it is part of an plugin found on the internet. I wanted to add some animation to that script. No other libaries used. The answer of N Rohler is working fine except some brackets. I managed to correct this. See my last post for the working code. My thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the `onOpen` and `onClose` properties into the same `modal()` initialization call:

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $("#basic-modal-content").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.hide();
            dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                dialog.data.slideDown('slow');   
            });
        });
    },
    onClose: function (dialog) {
        dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                $.modal.close();
            return false;
        });
    }});
});
```

*Edit: As others have alluded to, I'm shooting in the dark since we don't even know what script you're using.*

Comment: Hi thanks for you solution. There are brackets missing in your code so it didn't work right away. the complete working code here:

Answer (score 0):

A little problem in the answer. For somebody else who can use it this is the complete code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
$("#basic-modal-content").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.data.hide();
        dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.slideDown('slow');   
        });
    });
},
    onClose: function (dialog) {
        dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
            $.modal.close();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
}});
```